# In Android or Java, is there a way to resize a two-dimensional matrix

Tags: java, android, resize

Let's say I have a 100 by 120 matrix, but I want to have a size of 120 by 120 or 100 by 100, is there any way I can transform this matrix?
In Python, I use opencv.resize, because this function can handle arrays directly, but in Android and Java, it seems that you can't handle arrays directly. Cvresize can handle cVARr data, is there any way to convert a two-dimensional array to Cvarr?
Or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

In java, if you want to work with static arrays (fixed size) which normal arrays are, you will need to create a new 2 dimensional array of 120x120 size for example because you can't change the size of a static array. All its elements will be initialized to 0 by default, finally you just need to copy your 100x120 matrix in that array leaving all the untouched elements to 0.

If you are working with dynamic arrays (variable size) which is a variable-size list data structure like ArrayList, you dont need to create a new array beacuse you can manipulate the size of this ArrayList. So you just increase its size or decrease It depending on what dimensions you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it's static,but i don't want leave all the untouched elements to 0 ,such as i get a array:  {{1,3},{7,9}},it's 2*2,i want to resize it to be 2*3,like {{1,2,3},{7,8,9}},Maintain the relationships between the original array values.